# Можно ли использовать бинарный поиск для находжения последнего вхождения элемента в массив?

Tags: java, c++, python, алгоритм, двоичный-поиск

Дан массив из n элементов, упорядоченный в порядке неубывания, найти первое
и последнее вхождение числа в массив. Так как массив отсортирован, напрашивается использование бинарного поиска. Я использовал его для нахождения первого вохождения, но не знаю как его изменить, чтобы искать последнее вхождение.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Просто использовать разное поведение при решении, в какую сторону двигаться, если нашли значение, равное искомому. Пример на Java:

```
int binarySearch(int[] a, int fromIndex, int toIndex, int key, boolean last) {
    int low = fromIndex;
    int high = toIndex - 1;

    while (low <= high) {
        int mid = (low + high) >>> 1;
        int midVal = a[mid];

        if (midVal < key || (last && midVal == key))
            low = mid + 1;
        else if (midVal > key || (!last && midVal == key))
            high = mid - 1;
    }
    return last ? high : low;
}
```

Comment: что-то у вас условия странные если честно. Зачем `|| (` нужны?

Comment: @Alex Chermenin,  правильно ли я понимаю что fromIndex должен быть равен 0, а toIndex len(a)-1?

Comment: @ЗвягинцевДенис Чтобы обойти весь массив: fromIndex равен 0, toIndex равен длине массива. В коде уже есть уменьшение на единицу для переменной high.

Comment: @AlexChermenin А проверка на существование элемента в массиве сильно замедлит работу алгоритма?

Comment: Можно не добавлять проверку на существование, просто если в результате индекс последнего вхождения оказался меньше, чем индекс первого - значит такого элемента нет, а по индексам можно определить, куда его вставить, чтобы сортировка не сбилась :)

Comment: AlexChermenin, объясните подробнее про проверку пожалуйста

Answer (score 1):

Если у вас массив отсортирован (а это обязательное условие для бинарного поиска), то одинаковые значения находятся рядом. Бинарным поиском вы найдете какое-то из них (необязательно первое или последнее), далее нужно найти границы подмассива (где искомое значение граничит с большим или меньшим), для чего тоже можно применить бинарный поиск (чтобы не искать перебором).

Comment: И сложность вдруг станет линейной. А если массив на миллион элементов и там таких чисел - полмиллиона

Comment: @KoVadim, да, согласен. Тогда надо в обе стороны искать первый несовпадающий элемент по принципу бинарного поиска.

Answer (score 1):

Применяйте бинарный поиск, только ищите не само число, а число +- epsilon, где epsilon - некое небольшой положительное число, гарантировано меньше разницы между двумя различными числами. Если это массив целых чисел - epsilon может быть равен 0.5. Да, только нужно понимать, что самого то числа в этом случае не найдем, но границу - да. Данный алгоритм можно "немного ускорить", если верхнюю границу искать не от начала до конца, а от нижний границы и до конца.

Comment: извращение) в С++ есть 2 версии поиска. В Java не знаю, но руками они отличаются ровно в 1 знаке (где <= или <).

Comment: да, я думал о lower_bound и upper_bound, но судя по вопросу хотят общий алгоритм.

Comment: @pavel, поясните пожалуйста

Comment: Вот ещё плавающей точки не хватало, если массив целых...

Answer (score 0):

Если с++, то алгоритм `std::equal_range` делает то, что требуется.

Answer (score 0):

В python это вообще реализуется двумя строками:

```
lower_bound = my_list.index(10)
upper_bound = len(my_list) - list(reversed(my_list)).index(10) - 1
```

Более оптимальный вариант:

```
lower_bound = my_list.index(10)
for k in range(lower_bound+1, len(my_list)+1):
    if my_list[k] != 10:
        break
upper_bound = k - 1
```

кол-во повторений: 10 000 000
список из 30 элементов

```
первый вариант: 16.31380480196094  
второй вариант: 10.351039482047781
```

Comment: а какая сложность?

Comment: @ЗвягинцевДенис, `.index` - O(1), `.len` - O(1), `reversed` - O(N). Где N - длина списка. Если я правильно посчитал, то выходит O(N+3)

Comment: @YaroslavSurzhikov на Java тоже можно в одну строчку `IntStream.range(0, array.length).reduce(-1, (l, r) -> array[r] == key ? r : l);`, только это уже не бинарный поиск :)

Comment: @YaroslavSurzhikov, а обработка исключений (ValueError) замедляют работу алгоритма?

Comment: @ЗвягинцевДенис да, замедляет. На счет сложности, увы - не подскажу. Проверка на вхождение в список - O(N)